# Include IDs of nested associations in ActiveModel serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

In some cases nested associations are embedded in the JSON, in others they are not. So far so good, that behaves the way I want. But I want that in the cases where they aren't embedded the IDs of the nested associations are still emitted.

E.g.:

```
class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :x, :y
    belongs_to :bar
end

class BarSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :z
end
```

When I serialize a `Foo` object without `include: [:bar]` I want the result to look like:

```
{
    "id": 123
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "bar": 456
}
```

And if `bar` would be a polymorphic association I'd like something like that:

```
{
    "id": 123
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "bar": {"id": 456, "schema": "Bar"}
}
```

Actually I would like the IDs to be strings (`"id": "123"`) because they should be black boxes for the API consumer and definitely not use JavaScript's `Number` type (which is `double` precision floating point!).

How do I do that? I didn't find any information about that.

Answer (score 0):

Define attribute `id` this way in FooSerializer to get it as a string:

```
attribute :id do
  object.to_s
end
```

"When I serialize a Foo object without include: [:bar] I want the result to look like:"

```
attribute :bar do 
  object.bar.id.to_s
end
```

"And if bar would be a polymorphic association I'd like something like that:"

```
attribute :bar do 
  {id: object.barable_id.to_s, schema: object.barable_type}
end
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this.

Comment: Yes, that's that part and I did put something like that in a `BaseSerializer`. But what about the rest?

Comment: But can't I do this at a central place without writing this again and again and again in our tens of serializers with several relations each?

Comment: I don't know if there is such global settings. The only way I could think of is monkeypatching the gem class which I would not recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that by using a `BaseSerializer` like this:

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :type

    def id
        if object.id.nil?
            nil
        else
            object.id.to_s
        end
    end

    def type
        # I also want all the emitted objects to include a "type" field.
        object.class.name
    end

    def self.belongs_to(key, *args, &block)
        attribute key do
            assoc = object.class.reflect_on_association(key)
            foreign_id = object.send(assoc.foreign_key)
            if foreign_id.nil?
                nil
            elsif assoc.polymorphic?
                {
                    type: object.send(assoc.foreign_type),
                    id: foreign_id.to_s
                }
            else
                foreign_id.to_s
            end
        end

        super
    end
end
```